# ElasticSearch: partial match with both case sensitive and insensitive search using a single index

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to create a mapping for a single index where I can do a `match` query (for partial field matching unlike `keyword`) that would satisfy both case sensitive and insensitive searches?

Example data:

```
{
    "description": "my Brown car"
}
```

Search case 1 - case insensitive: "brown": 1 hit <- this can be achieved with `text` field type and `match` query.

Search case 2 - case sensitive: "brown": no result. <- need `term` for case sensitivity but won't match because not whole field value.

I can't create a second index because I'm creating a `bool` query combining both. But I can have multiple fields such as `decription.keyword`, or `description.magic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multi-field option of Elasticsearch.

> It is often useful to index the same field in different ways for different purposes. This is the purpose of multi-fields.

For more information please check Elastic official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).

Comment: Right, I need to use the standard analyzer for the case insensitive search and a custom analyzer (standard with lower case filter turned off) for the case sensitive case and create a multi-field option.